# How do you add functions to $(window).load()?

Tags: events, load, jquery, onload

Just curious if there's an easy way to add functions to the `$(window).load()` event before it has fired. For example, if you call `$(window).load()` twice in the beginning of the page, only the function of the second call will execute `onload`.

Is there some sort of tool built into jQuery for adding to the `onload` event instead of replacing it? If so, how about for the `$(document).ready()` call?

Comment: Use use it twice. `$(window).load(function() {...}); $(window).load(function() {...});`

Comment: What do you mean "add functions to the $(window).load() event before it has fired"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function windowLoad(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}

function documentReady(func) {
    var oldonload = document.ready;
    if (typeof document.ready != 'function') {
        document.ready = func;
    } else {
        document.ready = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

They actually do stack in the order specified. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/73D9Z/

I've used window.ready()

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    alert('window ready 1');
});

$(window).ready(function(){
    alert('window ready 2');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('document ready 1');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('document ready 2');
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between `$(window).ready()` and `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @trusktr. There is no $(window).ready(). It is $(document).ready(handler)

Comment: @hasan, but the above example seems to work with $(window).ready()!

Comment: @JohnP The link you posted I already know.... but this answer shows $(window).ready(), *not* $(window).load()... and it still seems to work...

Comment: @trusktr Why wouldn't window.ready work? These are just different event handlers.

Comment: @JohnP. Where is $(window).ready() mentioned in the post you provided? It talks about $(window).load()

Comment: @trusktr. I am unable to find information about this $(window).ready() event anywhere through google. All I find is $(window).load() and $(document).ready(). If you know any link where I can get more information about it, then do let me know.

Comment: @trusktr. Anyways, the point is that $(window).load() gets called once, when the window loads. So you could use stacking as mentioned by @JohnP. If in the example answer above you put $(window).ready() after $(document).ready() then $document.ready() executes first. Hence I believe, which ever of these event comes first, gets executed first. But in the case of $(document).ready() and $(window).load(), $(document).ready() always gets executed first.

Comment: I agree, but I've found that with more complicated scripts where window.load events are embedded inside jQuery functions, one or the other will get executed first (and the order matters, but it is random depending on the users browser cache), and I've had to create flags inside them to determine witch one executes first. In some cases, one will execute and the other won't.

Comment: For example, if a stand alone $(window).load() executes first, then one that is nested inside a jQuery event won't execute. If the script happens to read the one inside the jQuery event before the standalone one and all content is already loaded (e.g. user has all content cached in the browser) then the window.load that is inside the jQuery event will fire if the jQuery event happens before the standalone window.load happens.

Comment: It's pretty complicated, but I've figured it out with hours of testing and flags so I can tell in which situation the window.load calls happen (if they happen).

Comment: By the way, I figured all this out _after_ posting this question. :D

Answer (score 1):

$(window).load() gets executed after a page is rendered.

$(document).ready(handler) executes the function passed as parameter, after the DOM is ready and before the page is rendered.